# how to convert {{}} into sting varible in php

Tags: php, angularjs

i have a code in this code i get the check box data gender from database by angular the data is {{us.gender}} and its print succefully 'M'
i store it in `$gen="{{us.gender}}`", it print  M also but when i use it my php code then `$gen` value not work as string.
and when i chenge `$gen="M"`.the code is work i not under stand what is going on

```
<?php $gender="{{us.gender}}"?>
   <div class="form-group col-md-9">
  <label for="gender">Gender:<?php echo $gender;?></label>
<label class="radio-inline">

  <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if($gender=="M"){ echo "checked";}?>  value="m">Male
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if($gender =="f") { echo "checked"; }?>  value="f">Female
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if($gender =="o") { echo "checked"; }?>  value="o">other
</label>
  </div>
```

the code is work when i use `$gen="M"`
and i use `$gen="{{us.gender}}"`;
and then i print $gen it also print M
but in code its not work

Comment: That's because `{{}}` is an instruction to a template engine like Laravel's blade, not a PHP language construct

Comment: now what i do for this code ?

Comment: You are probably trying to mix angular with php in the wrong way. Remember that PHP is processed on server-side, and angular on client-side, that are totally isolated, so you cant set a php variable using a angular variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do such thing. You are trying to set a PHP variable using an Angular (javascript) variable. That is impossible:

PHP is processed on [Server-side](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side), so when PHP reads your code, it just can't understand the `{{ }}` template syntax that belongs to AngularJS. It just output's as you typed.

If your data came from angular, so use Angular tools to solve the problem:

## AngularJS solution (1.x)

You need to use the directive [ngChecked](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) to solve it:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-9">
  <label for="gender">Gender:{{ us.gender }}</label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <!-- NOTE THAT ON YOUR ORIGINAL CODE YOU ARE MIXING UPPERCASE AND LOWERCASE `M` CHAR -->
    <input type="radio" name="gender" ng-checked="us.gender == 'm'" value="m">Male
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" ng-checked="us.gender == 'f'" value="f">Female
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" ng-checked="us.gender == 'o'" value="o">other
  </label>
</div>
```